# Connecting to a Derby Database through JDBC fails

Tags: java, database, database-connection, derby

I'm trying to build a simple spring app which needs to have the ability to communicate with a database. Following a tutorial I have completed the entire code of my app however when I run my app I get this:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDruver]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverManagerDataSource.java:130)
    at main.Application.main(Application.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDruver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverManagerDataSource.java:127)
    ... 1 more
```

Here is the code which sets the data source and the jdbc:

```
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDruver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:derby:c:\\temp\\database\\test01;create=true");
        ds.setUsername("");
        ds.setPassword("");
        siod.setDataSource(ds);
```

I used SQuirrel to create my db. I'm 100% certain that is the path. Here is an image which tells what path the db has:
http://postimg.org/image/4tbfsxql9/

I'm sure there a simple answer to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct spelling is "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" not EmbeddedDruver.

If that doesn't fix it, check that you have your classpath set to include the Derby jar(s).  This can either be as explained [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html#derby_configure) or by including the Derby jar(s) with other jars in the library of your application.